# How do I use libTCOD graphical tiles if `char` cannot fit a number >=256?

Tags: rust, libtcod

I am trying to add graphical tiles to my roguelike using the [tcod-rs](https://github.com/tomassedovic/tcod-rs) library.

The root console's `put_char_ex` function (or the C version, `TCOD_putwchar`) both take only `char`s. To use tiles, as per the [Python tutorial](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_Python%2Blibtcod,_extras#Using_Graphical_Tiles), you must use tile numbers higher than 256 because the default bitmap font has 256 characters. `char` cannot represent these high numbers, so I'm stuck. How should I do this?

Comment: Understood. That might actually solve my problem. I'll remove the C++ tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Console::put_char_ex` method](https://github.com/tomassedovic/tcod-rs/blob/63b6341e7489b9c319f33e80a677393dedbfb71a/src/console.rs#L762-L772) indeed takes `char`. However, [Rust's `char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html) is not the same as C's:

> `char` is always four bytes in size.

You should be able to fit whatever numeric value you need.

---

> (or the C version, `TCOD_putwchar`)

Note that `put_char_ex` actually calls `ffi::TCOD_console_put_char_ex`; I'm not sure where `TCOD_putwchar` came from.

Comment: Awesome. Your comment above did indeed answer my question. TCOD_putwchar came from me searching `tcod_sys` for anything that "put chars". `ffi::TCOD_console_put_char_ex` didn't come up that I know of. Good to know!